# Loopback getting only one Object from property Array of Object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, loopback

I'm use loopback and mongodb. Right now I have a Model and one of its property type is array of object. The document in mongo will look like this

```
{
    "_id" : "sgG6G9XTvvjj7uxwQ",
    "name" : "test",
    subscription: [
        {
             "id":3324,
             "state":"Currently",
             "type": "A",
             "startDate": "Date"

        },
        {
             "id":5465,
             "state":"Futuristic",
             "type": "A",
             "startDate": "Date"
        },
        {
             "id":6575,
             "state":"Futuristic",
             "type": "A",
             "startDate": "Date"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have already tried

```js
 await this.clientsRepository.find({ where: { _id:'5d07ee4515741e0fbcfdbad1',
'subscription.state': 'Currently' },fields: { 'subscription.$': true } } })
```

I do expect only one object like this

```
{
   "id":3324,
    "state":"Currently",
    "type": "A",
    "startDate": "Date"
}
```

Comment: Your sample code seems to be missing opening quote around `subscription.$` -- could this be the source of your troubles?

Comment: yes but if i use { 'subscription': true } it will return all  objects in the array and with { 'subscription.$': true }  it return an empty array

Comment: I'm not 100%, but looks like there are two things mixed up: 1) 'subscription.$` is MongoDB thingie, it works if you MongoDB API, like mongo shell; 2) `fields: { ... }` is loopback thingie, and it does not know anything about mongo projections, you can only specify fields to include or exclude there. So, combining these conceptions does not do anything, from loopback's PoV that's just some unknown field. Probalby you can fetch all results, and then do some simple mapping to use only subdocument.

Comment: I think it's true thanks you  answer is helpful